# Smoochbot not replying

Tags: heroku, smooch

I tried setting up [smooch-bot](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot) via the [Heroku example](https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example). I followed the directions and opened the heroku app and chatted with the bot, but I don't receive any replies. The messages I type are being forwarded to smooch because I am receiving email notifications from Smooch... but there are no replies from smooch-bot in the chat window.

I am not a programmer so I've tried to follow the directions. I am deploying the app via a Dropbox connection. Is it normal that the Heroku folder in my Dropbox is empty? I tried uploading `script.js` into Dropbox > Apps > Heroku and Dropbox > Apps > Heroku > mybot, but I'm still not getting replies.

I am not sure where I went wrong. Could somebody help me point in the right direction?

Comment: Apparently not being a native English speaker is a crime on Stackoverflow...and got my question downvoted.  The prejudice is strong with this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Dropbox with Heroku, its not enough to simply edit your script file. You have to explicitly deploy your Dropbox changes via the Heroku dashboard, like this:

[image]

Also, to debug any issues with your bot script specifically, I've documented some troubleshooting steps here:

https://github.com/smooch/smooch-bot-example#troubleshooting-your-bot

To summarize, you need to install the [heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/), log in on the command line and view your app's error logs with `heroku logs -a your-app`.